# Error 2001 in Azure Data Factory executing a Stored Procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

We are trying to execute and stored procedure from ADF, however we are getting this error message

```
The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)
```

We have checked on internet a solution for this, but the official docs make reference to this error only during the execution of a Web activity:

[image]

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/700102/how-to-scale-out-the-size-of-data-moving-using-azu
```

However, here we are not moving data throught ADF, we are just executing a SP that populates a table based on another one in the same Data Base.

What could be a possible explanation for this error?

Comment: It sounds like, whether intended or not, the SP is returning data.

Comment: How are you executing stored procedure? if you are executing it with lookup activity and the procedure is returning some values it will throw you this error if the output is beyond 4 MB try to use stored procedure activity to execute stored procedure.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad. We are using the Stored procedure activity.

Comment: can you add screenshots what you are exactly trying to do for better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with this kind of limit related errors, there should be a workaround in diversifying the load.

See this recent post about this, the responder suggests a workaround with ForEach activity:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/700102/how-to-scale-out-the-size-of-data-moving-using-azu

I do remember similar problems with APIs when you dont use pagination in the activity, then it would go easily over the limit, then it would throw The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests error (I know yours isnt the same, but they are similar). Instead, implementing an iterative process to go through pagination have resolved this error, for example. An iterative process should provide the solution

Comment: Hi @Ziya. Thanks for your reply. Yes, we understood the problem. Now we are working in paginating the SP to solve this issue.